# Refs a slot to define the parent function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

## I have 2 components:

### Modal component

- This component simply displays his `slot content`.
- In this modal I have two methods `submit` and `cancel`.

### ContractForm Component

- This is a simple component who displays a form.

### What I want ?

So I want to actually define the `submit method`, what it does, in the `ContractForm component` (child) but use it in the `Modal component`(parent)?

---

## My code

I tried to ref the `ContractForm component` and call the method defined in the `ContractForm`from the `Modal component` like this.

#### html

```
  <modal>
    <contract-form ref="modalcontent"></contract-form>
  </modal>
```

#### Modal component

```
<template>
  <div class="modal">
    <slot :submit-modal="submitModal" ref="modalContent"></slot>
    <button @click="submitModal">Submit</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods:{
    submitModal: function () {
      this.$refs.modalcontent.submitModal()
  },
}
</script>
```

#### ContractForm Component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Modal content</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods:{
    submitModal: function () {
      alert('test')
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

## The problem

The reference doesn't work, when I `console.log(this.$refs)` this returns an empty object. I think the `refs` does'nt work because this is a `slot`(innerHtml)

Someone can help me please ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right in your assumption that the `slot` tag cannot be referenced using a `ref` tag.

In your case, it'd be better to have the modal component emit a `submit` event when the "Submit" button is clicked:

```
<template>
  <div class="modal">
    <slot></slot>
    <button @click="$emit('submit')">Submit</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

And then in the parent component scope, you can specify that the form component's `submitModal` function is the handler for the modal's `submit` event.

```
<modal @submit="$refs.modalcontent.submitModal()">
  <contract-form ref="modalcontent"></contract-form>
</modal>
```